# How To implement unshift method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, function, methods

i need make function like this:

```
Function add(arr,...newVal){

}

array = [1,2,3];
add(array,0)
console.log(array);        //i need here to print [0,1,2,3]
```

iam make function as push like that:

```
Function add(arr,...newVal){
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
arr[arr.length]=newVal[i];
}return arr.length;
}

array = [1,2,3];
add(array,4)
console.log(array);        // here to print [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: why don't use Array.unshift() ?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift
why don't use Array.push() ?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const unshift = (arr, ...newVal) => {
    let i= arr.length + newVal.length -1;
    for( i ; i >= newVal.length; i--) {
        arr[i] = arr[i - newVal.length ];
    }

    for(i; i >= 0; i--) {
        arr[i] = newVal[i];
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const unshift = (arr, newVal) => {
    for(let i = arr.length; i > 0; i--) {
        arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
    }
    arr[0] = newVal;
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: but here sir i cant add more than one items